# If my computer desk is knocked will my Hard-Drive get damaged?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I knocked the desk that my computer was sitting on and I am wondering whether I may have damaged my computer disk. How would I check its status for Windows 10?

Comment: Unlikely as hard disk are designed to handle some reasonable amount of shock. You can of course check you hard disk for errors. See [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: I edited my question: How would I check when using Windows 10?

Comment: You can also check NTFS status: open Windows Explorer, right-click on the hard drive letter, select *Properties*, and on the *Tools* tab select *Check*.

Comment: @GoalBike The links apply to Windows 10 as well.

Comment: So if I scanned the drive and no errors were found does that mean I'm all good?

Answer (score 1):

## Probably not.

Hard drives are usually pretty tough. Bumping the desk should not have damaged it.

I still recommend going through your files and making sure they are not corrupted. **Be sure to check multiple files** as one platter could be damaged and one not. If it is damaged, I recommend **backing up now** to another drive in the event that other sectors fail.